# How can I revert ubuntu settings after gnome-shell install

Tags: unity, gnome, lightdm, settings, lock-screen

I have Ubuntu 13.04 32 bit. Recently, I installed Gnome 3 because I wanted to try something new. It looked and felt awful, so I removed it via ppa-purge.

Unfortunately, some of my setting were altered by Gnome 3 which are mainly cosmetic but nonetheless annoying. Some examples:
- "Lock/Switch Account" in the upper right menu does not show the beautiful Unity lock screen any more but an ugly white box
- The GRUB bootloader screen is now blue
- When booting Ubuntu, the standard Gnome Wallpaper appears before lightdm shows
- Window title font looks different now

Does someone know how I get back to a clean Unity?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you run `ppa-purge` first like so (assuming you added the standard Gnome team PPA.  You also need to do this for every PPA you installed.  Do this *before* uninstalling the packages.

```
ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
```

Then remove all of the gnome related stuff (if it's installed):

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge gnome-shell 
sudo apt-get remove --purge ubuntu-gnome-desktop 
sudo apt-get remove --purge ubuntu-gnome-default-settings 
sudo apt-get remove --purge gnome-tweak-tool
```

Then run

```
unity --reset
unity --reset-icons
```

That should take care of it.

On a purely personal note, you may want to give Gnome 3 a try for a little longer and just read through the keyboard operations (especially the "Windows" key) and the available Gnome extensions.  It is a truly amazing work of UI engineering and design, fine-tuned for efficiency and customization.  The appearance can be micro-managed to be perfectly you.  Now that I know how to use it, I don't think I'll ever be able to use anything else and be happy.

Answer (score 1):

1. you need to install **unity-tweak-tool**. It should be in the official repository.

   Then open it. Choose 'theme' and select '**Ambiance**'.

   In addition you can tweak Fonts: The default Unity font is '**Ubuntu**', and the efault Window title font may be '**Ubuntu Medium**'.

   And tweak scrolling: choose Overlay.
2. Edit `/etc/default/grub`

   You should respect your own defaults. Change `echo debian` to `echo Ubuntu` on the line:

   ```
   GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=\`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Ubuntu\`
   ```

   And change `quiet splash` to `quiet` on the line

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"
   ```
3. No let we need to set up some links

   These commands will require root permission either from `sudo` or switching to root with `su`. Use the terminal and run.

   ```
   cd /lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo
   ln -s -r ubuntu-logo.plymouth ../default.plymouth
   ln -s -r ubuntu-logo.grub  ../default.grub 
   ln -s -r ../ubuntu-text/ubuntu-text.plymouth ../text.plymouth
   ```

   You should check if these targets exist. If not, you can simply remove them (`../default.plymouth`, etc). This step only affects whether a purple background or some console info would be shown after grub and before unity-greeter.
4. Finally , (better backup your */boot* directory and) execute

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```

Comment: The following line `GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=\`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Ubuntu\\`` gives an error of `/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 15: /etc/default/grub: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution` on `sudo grub-update` command in Ubuntu 13.10. It seems it has to be without the ending slash \ after `Ubuntu`.

Comment: It's worth to comment that in step 3 could be used: ``# update-alternatives --config default.plymouth`` and ``# update-alternatives --config text.plymouth``